# Apple Mail signature changes alignment of an element on Gmail

Tags: gmail, vertical-alignment, email-signature

I'm trying to complete a quite simple e-mail signature, and I had to work on Apple Mail first.

The following code works fine in Apple Mail and even on browsers, but Gmail changes the alignment of the div id="confidential", originally set to the bottom of its container id="first_col".

Is it a code's structural error or a matter of "semantic incompatibility" and I've to set different css?

I share the code here:
[my-mail-signature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VF3Mw.jpg)
[my-mail-signature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8kYQ.jpg)

here some screenshots too:
[Apple Mail signature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sesoj.jpg)
[changes on Gmail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsICC.jpg)

Thank u all in advance!